# Where is the line for solo mining?

Tags: mining-pools, solo-mining

In the [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/5d7fz3/good_hashrate_to_solo_mine/), they discussed if 15Kh/s is good hashrate.
Someone argues that he wouldn't solomine below 50kh.
But gingeropolous finds its enough to solo mine.
And the post was 9 months ago.

On [pool list](http://moneropools.com/) I see few pools with 2.85 KH/s and I think isn't that already too low?

I am considering to switch from Ethereum mining to Monero Mining. But instead of joining a big pool to run a own small pool. I estimate that my rigs will bring about 4.4 KH/s.

Question: Is it worth to start own pool with 4.4 KH/s ?

Or rather should I join a small existing pool with small fee ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's up to personal preference, really.  On average, block reward is generally evenly distributed according to hashing power.  If you're okay with mining for months at a time without receiving a payout, then perhaps you're better off.  If you win a block while solo mining, you don't have to share the block reward with anyone, nor do you have to pay the fee to the mining pool.

Answer (score 2):

There is a solo mining calculator here: https://www.monero.how/monero-mining-calculator

This will give you an understanding of the probability of successfully mining a solo block on a daily/weekly/monthly/yearly basis.

Comment: thanks for link. 
I found also another calculator: https://www.coinwarz.com/calculators/monero-mining-calculator/